# change Ubuntu Server to use /bin/bash

Tags: server, bash

A Linode server has Ubuntu Server (16.04) so I added ubuntu-desktop and gnome-terminal. Accessing the server via VNC I can open a terminal and it uses `/bin/sh` which has no command line editing and is generally hard to use interactively.

Using `chsh --shell /bin/bash` has no effect.

Editing the terminal's `Profile Preferences` to enable "Run command as login shell" makes no difference.

A reboot makes no difference.

Logging in via `ssh` to the same server gives a `bash` command line. It is only the terminal inside the VNC session that uses `sh`.

How do I fix this or is this supposed to be fun?

Comment: What command is configured to run in gnome terminal's profile?

Comment: @muru, I don't know how to find that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the terminal go to `Preferences > Profiles` and create a new one. In the `Command` tab select `Run a custom command instead of my shell` and set it to `/bin/bash`.

Select the new profile as the one to be the `Profile used when launching a new terminal` by clicking the drop-down list.

The pre-existing `Unnamed` profile can be deleted.